# Editing in ArcGIS Pro: Tracing to Modify Polygon

Tags: editing, arcgis-pro

Currently trying to update city area polygons based on parcel lines. Some of the pre-existing area annexation polygons need to be drawn exactly coincident to the parcel line.

I normally do this in arcmap using the tracing tool, but Pro does not offer tracing while modifying a polygon, so I'll have to go back and do extra topology correction. Is there a workflow that does the equivalent?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks Sean. I feel like a dope, I guess there's the sub-selection of tools where I simply need to select trace under reshape as you pointed out.